# Cannot move an image

Tags: java, awt, acm-java-libraries

I am trying to move an image from right to left. The image I am trying to move is
drawTrain method in another class. I think I have to use drawTrain method with move() method.
However, I do not know how to do that.. Or I'm totally wrong and there has to be another solution. So far, I tried to use something like

```
train.drawTrain.move(movex, 0);
train.drawTrain(0, 0).move(movex, 0);
```

well.. failed.. I tried to search and google and everything, but I'm just sitting and spending several hours. If what I am trying to do is right, how can I move a method in another class? If not, what did I do wrong and how can I fix them?

my driver class

```
public class Driver extends GraphicsProgram
{
//~ Instance/static variables .............................................

//~ Constructor ...........................................................

// ----------------------------------------------------------
/**
* The run() method of the Driver Class.
* Creates an instance of the Train Class.
* Responsible for animating the train across the screen.
*/
public void run()
{

    Train train = new Train(getGCanvas());
    int movex = -20;

    while(true)
    {
        train.drawTrain(1400, 100);
        train.move(movex, 0);
        pause(60);
    }

}
//~ Methods ...............................................................
}
```

Train class.. and I am trying to call a method in this class in Driver class.

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.*;
import acm.util.*;
import acm.program.*;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 *  This is the Train class with the basic methods already created.
 *  Write the correct code for all of the methods, and replace this comment.
 *  Please refer to the assignment for more instructions.
 * 
 */
public class Train extends GraphicsProgram
{
//~ Instance/static variables .............................................

private GCanvas canvas;

/* Dimensions of the frame of a train car */
private static final double CAR_WIDTH = 75;
private static final double CAR_HEIGHT = 36;

/* Distance from the bottom of a train car to the track below it */
private static final double CAR_BASELINE = 10;

/* Width of the connector, which overlaps between successive cars */
private static final double CONNECTOR = 6;

/* Radius of the wheels on each car */
private static final double WHEEL_RADIUS = 8;

/* Distance from the edge of the frame to the center of the wheel */
private static final double WHEEL_INSET = 16;

/* Dimensions of the cab on the engine */
private static final double CAB_WIDTH = 35;
private static final double CAB_HEIGHT = 8;

/* Dimensions of the smokestack and its distance from the front */
private static final double SMOKESTACK_WIDTH = 8;
private static final double SMOKESTACK_HEIGHT = 8;
private static final double SMOKESTACK_INSET = 8;

/* Dimensions of the door panels on the boxcar */
private static final double DOOR_WIDTH = 18;
private static final double DOOR_HEIGHT = 32;

/* Dimensions of the cupola on the caboose */
private static final double CUPOLA_WIDTH = 35;
private static final double CUPOLA_HEIGHT = 8;

//~ Constructor ...........................................................

// ----------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Creates a new Train object.
 * @param myCanvas the GCanvas where the train will be drawn.
 */
public Train(GCanvas myCanvas)
{
    canvas = myCanvas;
}

//~ Methods ...............................................................

/**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 */
public void drawTrain(double x, double y)
{
    double trainWidth = 4 * CAR_WIDTH + 6 * CONNECTOR;
    double dx = CAR_WIDTH + CONNECTOR;
    drawEngine(x, y);
    drawBoxCar(x + dx, y, Color.GREEN);
    drawBoxCar(x + dx + dx, y, Color.BLUE);
    drawCaboose(x + 3 * dx, y);


}

//Private Methods

/**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 */
private void drawEngine(double x, double y)
{
    drawCarFrame(x, y, Color.BLACK);
    drawSmokeStack(x, y - CAR_HEIGHT - 11, Color.BLACK);
    drawEngineCab(x + 11, y - CAR_HEIGHT - 11, Color.BLACK);
    drawCowCatcher(x, y - 10);
}

/**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 * @param color explain variable "color"
 */
private void drawBoxCar(double x, double y, Color color)
{
    drawCarFrame(x, y, color);

    double xRight = x + CONNECTOR + CAR_WIDTH / 2;
    double xLeft = xRight - DOOR_WIDTH;
    double yDoor = y - CAR_BASELINE - DOOR_HEIGHT;
    canvas.add(new GRect(xLeft, yDoor, DOOR_WIDTH, DOOR_HEIGHT));
    canvas.add(new GRect(xRight, yDoor, DOOR_WIDTH, DOOR_HEIGHT));


}

/**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 */
private void drawCaboose(double x, double y)
{
    drawCarFrame(x, y, Color.RED);
    drawCupola(x + CONNECTOR, y - CAR_HEIGHT - CAR_BASELINE, Color.RED);
}

/**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 */
private void drawCarFrame(double x, double y, Color color)
{
    double x0 = x + CONNECTOR;
    double y0 = y - CAR_BASELINE;
    double top = y0 - CAR_HEIGHT;
    GLine frame = new GLine(x, y0, x + CAR_WIDTH + 2 * CONNECTOR, y0);
    canvas.add(frame);
    drawWheel(x0 + WHEEL_INSET, y - WHEEL_RADIUS);
    drawWheel(x0 + CAR_WIDTH - WHEEL_INSET, y - WHEEL_RADIUS);
    GRect r = new GRect(x0, top, CAR_WIDTH, CAR_HEIGHT);
    r.setFilled(true);
    r.setFillColor(color);
    canvas.add(r);
}

/**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 */
private void drawWheel(double x, double y)
{
    double r = WHEEL_RADIUS;
    GOval wheel = new GOval(x - r, y - r, 2 * r, 2 * r);
    wheel.setFilled(true);
    wheel.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.add(wheel);
}

/**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 */
private void drawSmokeStack(double x, double y, Color color)
{
    GRect smokeStack = new GRect(x + 15, y - SMOKESTACK_HEIGHT, SMOKESTACK_WIDTH, SMOKESTACK_HEIGHT);
    smokeStack.setFilled(true);
    smokeStack.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.add(smokeStack);
}

/**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 */
private void drawEngineCab(double x, double y, Color color)
{
    GRect cab = new GRect(x + CAB_WIDTH, y - CAB_HEIGHT, CAB_WIDTH, CAB_HEIGHT);
    cab.setFilled(true);
    cab.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.add(cab);
}

/**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 */
private void drawCowCatcher(double x, double y)
{
    GLine cowCatcher1 = new GLine(x + CONNECTOR, y - CAR_HEIGHT / 2, x, y);
    canvas.add(cowCatcher1);
    GLine cowCatcher2 = new GLine(x + CONNECTOR, y - CAR_HEIGHT / 2, x + CONNECTOR / 2, y);
    canvas.add(cowCatcher2);
}

  /**
 * This is a placeholder javadoc comment.
 * @param x explain variable "x"
 * @param y explain variable "y"
 */
private void drawCupola(double x, double y, Color color)
{
    GRect cupola = new GRect(x + 20, y - CUPOLA_HEIGHT, CUPOLA_WIDTH, CUPOLA_HEIGHT);
    cupola.setFilled(true);
    cupola.setFillColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.add(cupola);
}
}
```

Comment: Is that all of the code you have? It seems like the move method is missing for the Train class.

Comment: oh, that is another way I tried.. I learned moving objects before, but I did not learn move method. Does move method look like this?
private void move(double x, double y)
{
...??
}
honestly, i've never made a move method..

Comment: Oh, more bloody ACM rubbish.  No, not your code, the ACM package itself is rubbish, and teachers should have stopped using it a decade ago.

Comment: probably you forgot to call invalidate() to trigger UI refresh

Comment: how can I call invalidate()? I'm just a beginner of java..:(